# How can I get the value of my clicked row

Tags: jquery

How can I Get the value of a TD from my clicked TD in my rendered GridView  ?

For example: I need the value of my second TD when I click in my fifth TD

```
$("td:eq(8)", "#GridView1 tbody tr:eq(" + index + ")").html("<div id='divActionProp'><span class='actionProposta' id='action_2'><b>Sell</b></span> | <span class='actionProposta' id='action_3'><b>Delete</b></span></div></td>");
```

I tryied the follow

```
example = $("td:eq(0)", "#GridView1 tbody tr").html();
```

but this return my first row (TR), and I want my clicked row (TR);

My Function that I tryied to get the value of a TD from a clicked TD in the same row

```
$('.acaoProposta').live('click', function () {       

    example  = $("td:eq(0)", "#grdDetalheProposta tbody tr").html(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say how you are processing the click event, but in a general sense within an event handler `this` refers to the element the event was triggered on, so:

```
$("#GridView1 tbody tr").click(function() {
   var example = $("td:eq(0)", this).html();
});
```

Update: Apparently your click is bound (using `.live()`) to a div within one of the other columns. No problem, again `this` refers to the clicked element so from there you can go up through the DOM to find the tr that it belongs to and then within that tr find the td you care about:

```
$('.acaoProposta').live('click', function () {
    var example = $("td:eq(0)", $(this).closest("tr")).html();
});
```

The [`.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) goes up through the DOM tree looking for the first ancestor element that matches the supplied selector.

Comment: But the click, I get from a CSS class inside a DIV, how can you see in the function  '.acaoProposta'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("table tr").click(function()
{

 alert($(this).html()); 

});
```

Check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/MRXM8/

Answer (score 0):

Since you **click**, you need to setup click event handler:

```
$('#GridView1 tbody tr').click(function(){
   alert(this.innerText || this.textContent); // get row html
});
```

To get contents of individual TDs though, you should have:

```
$('#GridView1 tbody tr td').click(function(){
   alert(this.innerText || this.textContent); // get cell html
});
```

Notice that you can use `$(this).html()` but using `this.innerText || this.textContent` is a bit faster.

Comment: But the click, I get from a CSS class inside a DIV, how can you see in the function '.acaoProposta'

Answer (score 0):

What's your HTML look like?

This could work:

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    alert($(this).find('td').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass tr instance to the search

```
$("#GridView1 tbody tr").click(function(){
   alert($('td:eq(0)', this).html());
});
```

For updated question:

```
$('.acaoProposta').live('click', function () {       

    example  = $("td:eq(0)", this).html(); 
});
```

this - is instance to clicked tr element.

Comment: But the click, I get from a CSS class inside a DIV, how can you see in the function '.acaoProposta'